# How do I create a function that returns true if a graph is a cycle

Tags: python, networkx

```py
connec2=[('1', '3'), ('1', '4'),('1','6'), ('2', '3'),('2', '7'),('3','8'),('3','6'),('3', '4'),
        ('4', '5') ,('4','9'),('4','6'),('5','10'),('7','8'),('8','11'),('11','9'),('9','10')]

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edges_from(connec2)



def is_hole(g):
    no=nx.number_of_nodes(g)

    if no >= 4:
        sub = nx.subgraph(g, g.nodes)

        s = []
        for n in sub.nodes:
            s.append(n)

        if nx.has_path(sub,s[0], s[no-1]):
            if adj(sub, s[0], s[no-1]):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False

    return False


l =is_hole(g)
print(l)
```

I'm trying to make a function on python, using `networkx` library, to return `True` if a graph is a hole (an induced cycle of length at least 4) or `False` otherwise. However I cant think of a way to do so.
I tried using `cycle_basis()` and `find_cycle()` but that doesn't work.
I also tried using `is_path()` and `has_path()`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Determining if a given (sub-)graph is a hole is straightforward. All you need to test is:

- Is the size of the graph > 4 (from the definition of hole)?
- After removing an edge (v1, v2), does the shortest path between v1 and v2 contain all nodes in the remaining graph (from the definition of a chordless graph)?

For the more general case, i.e. efficiently detecting holes in graphs, see: Nikolopoulos & Palios (2004) Hole and antihole detection in graphs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Determine if a given graph is a chordless cycle with length four or more.

See also
--------
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordless_cycle
"""

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx


def is_chordless_cycle(graph):
    edges = list(g.edges)
    source, target = edges[0]
    graph.remove_edge(source, target)
    path = nx.shortest_path(graph, source, target)
    return set(path) == set(graph)


def is_hole(graph):
    if len(graph) >= 4:
        return is_chordless_cycle(graph)
    else:
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # positive example
    edges = [
        (0, 1),
        (1, 2),
        (2, 3),
        (3, 0)
    ]
    g = nx.Graph(edges)
    print(is_hole(g))
    # True 

    # negative example
    edges = [
        (1, 3),
        (1, 4),
        (1, 6),
        (2, 3),
        (2, 7),
        (3, 8),
        (3, 6),
        (3, 4),
        (4, 5),
        (4, 9),
        (4, 6),
        (5, 10),
        (7, 8),
        (8, 11),
        (11, 9),
        (9, 10)
    ]
    g = nx.Graph(edges)

    # fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    # nx.draw(g, ax=ax)
    # plt.show()

    print(is_hole(g))
    # False
```